# Show that it is impossible for there to be a set $X$ such that it is a subset of the set $X\times X$

Tags: set-theory

Ordered pairs $\left<x,y\right>$ can be defined as $\left<x,y\right> = \{x,\{x,y\}\}$. Use this definition of $\left<x,y\right>$ for defining $X \times X$.

Show that it is impossible for there to be a set $X$ such that it is a subset of the set $X\times X$.

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around why such a set could not be a subset of $X\times X$. Would anyone be able to walk me through this question? Much appreciated in advance.

Comment: $X=\emptyset $?

Comment: In addition to the empty set, I believe you need to assume that the Axiom of Foundation holds. Otherwise, if you have a set $x$ such that $x=\{x\}$, then $\langle x,x\rangle = \{x,\{x,x\}\} = \{x,\{x\}\} = \{x,x\} = \{x\} = x$, so $x\times x= \{x\}  = x$.

Comment: (Also, the ordered pair is usually defined as $\langle x,y\rangle = \{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$. I guess your definition might be a valid alternative, but I haven’t worked it through)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin It is (but has the disadvantage of requiring regularity in order to work).

Comment: It is true that the duplicate is slightly different, using the Kuratowski ordered pair definition instead. But the same argument works here essentially the same way.

Answer (score 2):

By the [axiom of regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory#2._Axiom_of_regularity_(also_called_the_axiom_of_foundation)) there exist a $u \in X$ such that $u \cap X = \emptyset$.

If $X \subset X \times X$ we can write $u = \{x, \{x,y\}\}$ with $x, y \in X$. But then $x$ belongs to both $u$ and $X$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify things:

Let $X$ be a set, and define $X\times X$ to be the set $\{<x, y>:x, y\in X\}$. We want to show that $X$ is not a subset of $X\times X$, unless $X$ is empty.

Suppose $X$ is a non-empty subset of $X\times X$. This means any element of $X$ is of the form $\{x, \{x, y\}\}$ for some elements $x, y\in X$. In particular, any element of $X$ contains an element of $X$.

Now let $x$ be any element of $X$. We can then build a sequence of sets: $x_0 = x$ and $x_n$ is an element of $X$ that is contained in $x_{n - 1}$.

The [axiom of regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity#No_infinite_descending_sequence_of_sets_exists) then says that this is impossible, as there is no infinite descending sequence of sets.

---

I probably used axiom of choice here. Not sure if that's necessary.

Comment: You didn't use the axiom of choice, and you do not need the sequence anyway.

Comment: I see, the other answer is more direct.

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle` for the delimeters, not `<` and `>`.